# I am getting error code 10061 when I try to check the availability of Port

Tags: c#, sockets, port

I am trying to find port availability with the help of below C# code, and i am getting exception "Error Code 10061: Connection refused " need some help in solving this issue. 
The ports which are open also are shown as closed so I am facing this porblem

```
class Program
{
    private string _HostURI;
    private static bool m_blnIsWinAuth = false;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Hostname tcp;
        bool udp = false;
        Program pr = new Program();
        tcp = pr.GetPortAvability("127.0.0.1", 80, true);
        Console.WriteLine(tcp);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public Hostname GetPortAvability(string _HostURI, int _PortNumber, bool isTCP)
    {
        Hostname returnValue = new Hostname();
        returnValue.HostName = _HostURI;
        returnValue.Result = false;

        IPAddress ipa = (IPAddress)Dns.GetHostAddresses(_HostURI)[0];

        try
        {
            Socket sock;
             if (isTCP)
                sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            else
                sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

            sock.Connect(ipa, _PortNumber);

            if (sock.Connected)
                returnValue.Result = true;
            else
                returnValue.Result = false;

            sock.Close();
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            if (se.ErrorCode == 10061)
                returnValue.Result = true;
            else
                returnValue.Result = false;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            returnValue.Result = false;
        }

        return returnValue;       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 10061 is *connection refused by server*
This makes sense to me because you are trying to connect to a socket with given IP address and port number. But there is no other socket waiting for a connection.
You need to find a different way. Look for 'endpoint'.

Comment: :Thank you but can you suggest some way to contact that port?

Comment: You can't connect. A connection needs another endpoint that is waiting for a connection. You could try to only *create the endpoint* on your side, which would fail for ports in use.